# How to retrieve data from database Phalcon php

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm using tutorial-master https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html the Create step from CRUD is awesome, I can input data to database. But I don't understand how to generating data from table using query.

this code didn't work because I use `$application = new Application($di);` not micro.

```
// Retrieves all robots $app->get('/api/robots', function () use ($app) {

$phql = "SELECT * FROM Robots ORDER BY name";
$robots = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);

$data = array();
foreach ($robots as $robot) {
    $data[] = array(
        'id'   => $robot->id,
        'name' => $robot->name
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);

});
```

I want to have 
`$query="SELECT * FROM ospos ORDER BY ospoId";` and output `$data = array(); echo jsone_encode($data)` and resulting same result as micro code.. please help Thank you.

Comment: `var_dump($robots)`,  That will print out the contents of that variable, to make sure it is what you think it should be.  For example is `$robot` truly an Object, or an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** your above query using models.

```
$robots = Robots::find([
    'order' => 'name'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any satisfying answer so i thought of commenting how i did this.
In a controller do the following:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
$this->aricleModel = new Articles();

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $articles = Articles::find();

        if ($articles) {
            foreach ($articles as $article) {
               echo $article->title;
               echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Assuming you already made the model. the key is this: `$this->aricleModel = new Articles();` Without it foreach won't work.